# How can I use before_save properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get syntax error if I code like this.
How can I fix?

```
before_save :handle_invitation_code, if: :just_confirmed

def just_confirmed?
  confirmed_at_changed? && confirmed_at_was.nil?
end

def handle_invitation_code
  ...
end
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Why would you tell us you have an error, and then not tell us what the error was? We're not psychic.

Comment: Have you tried `before_save :handle_invitation_code, if: 'self.just_confirmed?'` (yes yes, the if statement as a string, works for me in production currently in Rails 3.2.11 with `before_save :set_name, if: 'self.name.nil?'`)

Comment: @MrYoshiji I still get this:( undefined method `before_save' for UsersController:Class

Comment: @MrYoshiji am I supposed to code this in model? not in controller?

Comment: @MrYoshiji  Thanks! What if I want to access to current_user, and other user record in model, though. I thought it's impossible. I want to

Comment: You need to pass it from the controller to the model as an argument

Answer (score 2):

How about?

```
before_save :handle_invitation_code

def just_confirmed?
  confirmed_at_changed? && confirmed_at_was.nil?
end

def handle_invitation_code
  if self.just_confirmed?
  ...
  end
end
```

Or you would have to pass the code in `just_confirmed?` as a Proc to the `before_save`.

Comment: I still get undefined method `before_save' for UsersController:Class no method error

Comment: before_save is a `ActiveRecord` Callback.. The Controller inherits from `ActionController` which does not have that callback. I think you need `before_filter`.

Comment: Thanks. I want to execute this method only when after the user is confirmed by email with Devise.

Comment: Do you mean to say that just_confirmed? exists in `User` model?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. No. It exists in users_controller.rb